# Calculate a correlation matrix for all factor levels of a column

Tags: r

How can I calculate a correlation matrix for each level of the categorical variable, where the correlations are among all variables in the remaining columns?

For the example below, this means the correlation between q2 to q10 in each level of q1?.

```
A<-data.frame(q1=c("A","A","A","D","D","D","F","F","F","G","G","G","G","A","D"), 
      q2=sample(1:70, 15, rep=1), 
      q3=sample(1:60, 15, rep=1), 
      q4=sample(1:60, 15, rep=1), 
      q5=sample(1:103, 15, rep=1), 
      q6=sample(1:50, 15, rep=1), 
      q7=sample(1:101, 15, rep=1), 
      q8=sample(1:40, 15, rep=1), 
      q9=sample(1:100, 15, rep=1), 
      q10=sample(1:200, 15, rep=1))
```

Also, how can I show these correlations on a plot?

Comment: "all variables for each levels of the categorical variable(q1)" is unclear. In the sample data `q1` is not categorical. Do you mean all other rows for each level of q1?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you need `n` correlation matrices, one for each level of `q1`.

If that's the case, you can use a simple `for` loop to get them:

```
c <- list()
for(q in unique(data$q1)) {
  c[[q]] <- cor(data[data$q1 == q,2:10])
}
```

The `c` list will have an entry for each level of `q1`

Answer (score 2):

```
correlations <- lapply(split(A, A$q1), function(x) cor(x[,-1]))

> correlations
$A
            q2          q3          q4          q5         q6         q7          q8          q9         q10
q2   1.0000000 -0.44803503  0.50600715  0.93230347  0.4369729 -0.1247089  0.83257155  0.47128720 -0.40309437
q3  -0.4480350  1.00000000  0.53166771 -0.20412996 -0.9404926 -0.7119750  0.06469342 -0.36555367  0.95642170
q4   0.5060071  0.53166771  1.00000000  0.71679818 -0.5384897 -0.7141115  0.87705638 -0.04306433  0.57753545
q5   0.9323035 -0.20412996  0.71679818  1.00000000  0.1162383 -0.1865482  0.96352065  0.16325848 -0.08958274
q6   0.4369729 -0.94049256 -0.53848969  0.11623826  1.0000000  0.4923609 -0.13194449  0.64332166 -0.99763177
q7  -0.1247089 -0.71197500 -0.71411145 -0.18654820  0.4923609  1.0000000 -0.39564648 -0.34010040 -0.55069571
q8   0.8325715  0.06469342  0.87705638  0.96352065 -0.1319445 -0.3956465  1.00000000  0.08376171  0.16455409
q9   0.4712872 -0.36555367 -0.04306433  0.16325848  0.6433217 -0.3401004  0.08376171  1.00000000 -0.59118795
q10 -0.4030944  0.95642170  0.57753545 -0.08958274 -0.9976318 -0.5506957  0.16455409 -0.59118795  1.00000000

$D
             q2         q3          q4         q5          q6         q7          q8         q9         q10
q2   1.00000000 -0.6763867  0.95671018  0.9704899 -0.04887372  0.3729085  0.83267631 -0.2684279 -0.38379940
q3  -0.67638669  1.0000000 -0.58384573 -0.6513078 -0.60950525 -0.3943479 -0.62258512  0.8898461  0.69153886
q4   0.95671018 -0.5838457  1.00000000  0.8620453  0.01355672  0.5925750  0.63735667 -0.1899837 -0.51516909
q5   0.97048986 -0.6513078  0.86204530  1.0000000 -0.17072346  0.1417973  0.93960117 -0.2401559 -0.19646514
q6  -0.04887372 -0.6095053  0.01355672 -0.1707235  1.00000000  0.5915035 -0.23682009 -0.8533831 -0.83975896
q7   0.37290854 -0.3943479  0.59257503  0.1417973  0.59150349  1.0000000 -0.17116412 -0.3371096 -0.90364809
q8   0.83267631 -0.6225851  0.63735667  0.9396012 -0.23682009 -0.1711641  1.00000000 -0.2699661  0.02392984
q9  -0.26842790  0.8898461 -0.18998368 -0.2401559 -0.85338309 -0.3371096 -0.26996613  1.0000000  0.70740850
q10 -0.38379940  0.6915389 -0.51516909 -0.1964651 -0.83975896 -0.9036481  0.02392984  0.7074085  1.00000000

$F
            q2         q3          q4         q5         q6         q7         q8         q9         q10
q2   1.0000000  0.1439251 -0.36801650 -0.7892030 -0.4045654 -0.9979487  0.8095933  0.9463303  0.96088598
q3   0.1439251  1.0000000  0.86717169  0.4941522  0.8467606 -0.2069818 -0.4643589 -0.1836355  0.41235657
q4  -0.3680165  0.8671717  1.00000000  0.8614718  0.9992149  0.3077360 -0.8437394 -0.6487839 -0.09611375
q5  -0.7892030  0.4941522  0.86147184  1.0000000  0.8809138  0.7482684 -0.9994238 -0.9453351 -0.58825368
q6  -0.4045654  0.8467606  0.99921489  0.8809138  1.0000000  0.3451900 -0.8643422 -0.6784229 -0.13547310
q7  -0.9979487 -0.2069818  0.30773601  0.7482684  0.3451900  1.0000000 -0.7703543 -0.9236982 -0.97664447
q8   0.8095933 -0.4643589 -0.84373942 -0.9994238 -0.8643422 -0.7703543  1.0000000  0.9558589  0.61536300
q9   0.9463303 -0.1836355 -0.64878390 -0.9453351 -0.6784229 -0.9236982  0.9558589  1.0000000  0.81980673
q10  0.9608860  0.4123566 -0.09611375 -0.5882537 -0.1354731 -0.9766445  0.6153630  0.8198067  1.00000000

$G
             q2         q3         q4         q5         q6         q7          q8         q9        q10
q2   1.00000000 -0.5672060  0.9137473  0.9221046  0.4872684 -0.4363765  0.06508126  0.4942240 -0.4619742
q3  -0.56720597  1.0000000 -0.6033027 -0.2675167  0.1195274  0.7432619 -0.85226036 -0.0813887  0.9611281
q4   0.91374727 -0.6033027  1.0000000  0.9014109  0.6820842 -0.7236664  0.21082792  0.7548119 -0.4087825
q5   0.92210460 -0.2675167  0.9014109  1.0000000  0.7670341 -0.3702843 -0.21819900  0.7237786 -0.1032187
q6   0.48726838  0.1195274  0.6820842  0.7670341  1.0000000 -0.4108090 -0.35300010  0.9657497  0.3702882
q7  -0.43637648  0.7432619 -0.7236664 -0.3702843 -0.4108090  1.0000000 -0.70799246 -0.6287476  0.5407077
q8   0.06508126 -0.8522604  0.2108279 -0.2181990 -0.3530001 -0.7079925  1.00000000 -0.1025016 -0.8382874
q9   0.49422403 -0.0813887  0.7548119  0.7237786  0.9657497 -0.6287476 -0.10250163  1.0000000  0.1913168
q10 -0.46197421  0.9611281 -0.4087825 -0.1032187  0.3702882  0.5407077 -0.83828741  0.1913168  1.0000000
```

To display, you can use image,

```
par(mfrow=c(1, length(levels(A$q1))))
for(c in correlations) image(c)
```

although for interpretation, you may want a legend. For that, try the `ggplot2` code in Lapointe's answer

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. In my real data, I have lots of missing values. When I run this code the correlation would be NA. How can I modify this code to fix this issue. For example, How can I have use="complete.obs"?

Comment: No problem. To deal with missing obs, you could change ` cor(x[,-1]))` in the first line to ` cor(x[,-1], use="complete.obs"))` (or any of the other possible arguments to `use`)

Comment: When I use it , i got this error                                                                     Error in cor(x[, -1], use = "complete.obs") : no complete element pairs

Comment: that means there are too many missing observations to calculate a correlation. see Details in the help for `cor` for other options (to view help type `?cor` in the R console

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `cor(data)` and here's how to put it in a chart.

```
data_cor <- cor(data)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
melted_data <- melt(data_cor)

library(ggplot2)
d <-ggplot(data = melted_data, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value))
d +geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I need the correlation matrix for each levels of q1 separately.